# Which specific type of recurrent neural network (RNN) is required to solve this supervised sequence problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a variety of features and an sequence target variable of **fixed** dimension 1x20 e.g. [0,0,0,1,0,...]. I've been reading up on the potential of RNNs to predict sequences. What specific methods/architectures can be used to solve this problem? i.e. given a list of features, predict the full target vector.

Is sequence to sequence prediction useful here? i.e. convert the features into a vector so I'm predicting a target vector from an input feature vector.

Is there a name for these specific problems and is there a state of the art you'd recommend I look into (or any papers)?

Comment: It would help to have some more details as to what the target actually represents. Is the target actually a sequence? Does the ordering mean something, or is it arbitrary? The idea of a sequence to sequence model doesn't sound appropriate to me, just sticking the input features into a vector doesn't really make them a sequence. Perhaps you'd just be better off using a feedforward RNN with 20 output units?

Comment: Hey sorry about the details - So this problem is a cricket analytics question. The features include things like the country the game was played, the year, the team etc. and the target is a sequence of states in the game based on the bowling type (e.g. 0 could represent spin, 1 could represent seam - seam and spin are the two possible states and there are 20 time periods in a game). As a result each state could be influenced by previous states and the features.